# ANDROID: Finding the size of individual tables in a SqliteDatabase

Tags: android, size, sqlite

I am trying to do something along the following lines:

```
SELECT bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

I know that I can get the size of the whole database by

```
mDb = SQLiteDatabase;
long size = new File(mDb.getPath()).length();
```

Is it possible to get how much space an individual table takes up in storage in Android's SQLiteDatabase?

EDIT--

By the lack of response, I guess that it's not possible with SQLite. I am currently using a hack-ish way where I count the number of rows in the table and estimate how much space a single row takes (based on the given table schema).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mostly store binary or string data in a single column, you can use an aggregate query:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(the_column)) FROM the_table
```

This can give you a reasonable estimate even when the size of each row varies a lot (for example if you store pictures in the database). However, if you have many columns with a small amount of data in each, your approach (estimating a fixed size per row) is better.

On Android, you can implement it like the following:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = ... // your database
// you can cache the statement below if you're using it multiple times
SQLiteStatement byteStatement = database.compileStatement("SELECT SUM(LENGTH(the_column)) FROM the_table");
long bytes = byteStatement.simpleQueryForLong();
```

Comment: it returns the sum of length column how could i get result in byte please let me know... ?

Comment: AFAIK SQLite doesn't have a function for the number of bytes, unless you store the data as a binary blob instead of text. If you mostly have English text and use UTF-8, the number of bytes should be approximately equal to the number of characters.

Comment: I think you could CAST it to a BLOB when selecting: SELECT SUM(LENGTH(CAST(column_name AS BLOB))) FROM table_name